# Java - Excel Formula on an entire column - Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I need the same formula (H2-F2) on an entire column (H3-F3, H4-F4...) or atleast till 100, starting from J2, without creating a new row (already exists, gets the info from an existent excel file). Is there a way of doing it? here's my code so far:

```
int cRow = 1;
int a=2;
Row newRow = firstSheet.getRow(cRow); 
        
        while (newRow != null) {
        Cell cell2 = newRow.createCell(9);
        cell2.setCellFormula("H" + a + "-VALUE(F" + a + ")");
                a++;
                cRow++;
        }
```

Comment: The next rows needs to be fetched within the `while` loop. So try an additional  `newRow = firstSheet.getRow(cRow); ` after `cRow++` in the `while` loop.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you!! can't believe it was that simple